# how to add variable in jsx style attribute when there is already object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to do **text-align** in **textarea** tag by writing logic with the variable name **myStyle**, so the logic is working but then when I made a **toggle** switch for dark mode and added more styling as **object**. Then **myStyle** stop working. So the question is how to add **myStyle** variable in **style** attribute when there is already a given object what is the correct format?

```
export default function TextForm(prop) {
  const [text, setText] = useState("Enter text here");

  const [myStyle, setMyStyle] = useState({
    textAlign:'left'
  })
  const textAlign = ()=>{
    if(myStyle.textAlign === 'left'){
      setMyStyle({
        textAlign: 'center'
      })
    }
    else if(myStyle.textAlign === 'center'){
      setMyStyle({
        textAlign:'right'
      })
    }
    else{
      setMyStyle({
        textAlign:'left'
      })
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
    <div className='container' style={{color: prop.mode==='light'?'Black':'white'}}>
        <h2>{prop.heading} </h2>
        <div className="mb-3">
        <textarea className="form-control " style={myStyle,{ backgroundColor:prop.mode==='light'?'white':'grey', color:prop.mode==='light'?'black':'white'}} value={text}  onChange= {handleOnChange}  id="myBox" rows="6"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button className="btn btn-primary mx-1" onClick={textAlign} >Change Text Align</button>
    </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spread the existing object into a new one, and in that new one, list the additional properties desired.

```
<textarea
  className="form-control "
  style={{
    ...myStyle,
    backgroundColor:prop.mode === 'light' ? 'white' : 'grey',
    color: prop.mode === 'light' ? 'black' : 'white'
  }}
  value={text}
  onChange={handleOnChange}
  id="myBox"
  rows="6"
></textarea>
```

Though it'd be more elegant to toggle a CSS class on the element instead, and do this with CSS rules instead of through properties set via JS.